# EXC_BAD_ACCESS trying to read an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

In the following code, I try to read data from a plist:

```
 -(void)readPreferences 
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSMutableArray * myAppDefaults  = [defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"LastList"];
        myCustomObject * savedObject;
        NSUInteger i;
        for (i = 0; i < [myAppDefaults  count]; i++) 
        {
            NSArray * thisArray = [myAppDefaults  objectAtIndex:i];

            savedObject.value1 = [thisArray objectAtIndex:0];
            savedObject.value2 = [thisArray objectAtIndex:1];
            savedObject.value3 = [thisArray objectAtIndex:2];
            savedObject.value4 = [myAppDefaults  objectAtIndex:3];

            [objectsArray addObject:savedObject];
        }

    }
```

Somehow, when I try to set "savedObject.value1", I get an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error.

I realize this is quite likely basic memory management, or pointer/object kind of confusion, but I'm still learning.
I hope someone can help me out here.
Best regards
Sjakelien

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't initialized `savedObject` at the time you set the `value1` property. You will need to add:

```
savedObject = [[myCustomObject alloc] init];
```

before your `for` loop in order for it to be a valid object that you can set properties on.

Comment: Don't forget to send release or autorelease to that object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `mutableArrayValueForKey` in `NSUserDefaults`.
Try `arrayForKey:` instead, that will give you `NSArray*`.

Seems that values returned from `defaults` are immutable (make sense as you're getting stuff from file).

Check the returned value from `mutableArrayValueForKey`, I suspect it's nil.

On second look your code does not make much sense.
At no point you allocate savedObjects but you repeatedly insert it into array.
Even the way you are extracting the values does not seem correct.

I would suggest looking at NSUserDefautls reference in Apple documentation, it has examples of basic usage.

Comment: According to the documentation, mutableArrayValueForKey is "Available in iPhone OS 2.0 and later."
Anyway, the returned value is not NIL. It contains 12 objects. I guess that's the problem.
savedObject.value1 is an NSString, while the objectAtIndex:0 is an object. Maybe I should convert it somehow?

Comment: All NSStrings (that is, NSString objects) are objects.

Comment: You are right about the not-making-sense of my code. Luckily, I returned here in time, to stop myself from asking another stupid question. Thanks!